# Computing the sheaf of 1-forms on a toric variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, differential-forms, sheaf-theory, coherent-sheaves, toric-geometry

Consider projective space $P^{2}$ and its corresponding fan. We have the affine opens defined by $U_{\sigma_{0}} = Spec(\mathbb{C}[x,y])$, $U_{\sigma_{1}} = Spec(\mathbb{C}[x^{-1},x^{-1}y])$ and $U_{\sigma_{2}} = Spec(\mathbb{C}[xy^{-1},y^{-1}])$ cf (Example 3.1.9 Cox, Little, and Schenck).

Given these affine opens, how would one compute the sheaves $\Omega^{1}_{\mathbb{P}^{2}}(U_{\sigma_{i}})$ and the transition functions on the intersections $U_{\sigma_{i}} \cap U_{\sigma_{j}}$? (cf Exercise 8.2.4 Cox, Little, and Schenck).

I understand the construction via using the transformation of the differential forms with the Jacobian matrix, but I'm not sure how to work using the above approach. My main issue is that I'm not sure how to compute $\Omega^{1}_{\mathbb{P}^{2}}(U_{\sigma_{i}})$.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's recall the definition of the module of differentials on a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $R$: take the free $R$-module on the symbols $\{ dr \colon r \in R \}$ and mod out by the relations $d(r+s ) = dr + ds$, $d(rs) = sdr + r ds$, and $da = 0$ for $a \in \mathbb{C}$. Then, the sheaf $\Omega_{R/\mathbb{C}}^1$ on $\textrm{Spec}(R)$ is the "tilde" of this module. A useful fact for computations (which will be used below) is the following: it suffices to take the free module on the symbols $\{ dr_i \}_{i \in I}$, where $\{ r_i \in R \colon i \in I \}$ is a generating set (and then mod out by the appropriate relations).

On each piece of the given open affine cover of $\mathbb{P}^2_{\mathbb{C}}$, the modules of differentials are
$$
\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^1}^1 (U_{\sigma_0}) = \mathbb{C}[x,y] \cdot dx \oplus \mathbb{C}[x,y] \cdot dy
$$
\begin{align*}
\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^1}^1 (U_{\sigma_1}) 
&= \mathbb{C}[x^{-1},x^{-1} y] \cdot d(x^{-1}) \oplus \mathbb{C}[x^{-1}, x^{-1} y ] \cdot d(x^{-1} y)\\
&= \mathbb{C}[x^{-1}, x^{-1}y] \cdot x^{-2} dx \oplus \mathbb{C}[x^{-1}, x^{-1} y ] \cdot yx^{-2} dx \oplus \mathbb{C}[x^{-1}, x^{-1}y ] \cdot x^{-1} dy
\end{align*}
Knowing this, can you now compute $\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^1}^1(U_{\sigma_2})$? *Edit*: for the sake of completeness, the module of differentials on $U_{\sigma_2}$ is
\begin{align*}
\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^1}^1(U_{\sigma_2}) 
&= \mathbb{C}[xy^{-1}, y^{-1}] \cdot d(xy^{-1}) \oplus \mathbb{C}[xy^{-1}, y^{-1}] \cdot d(y^{-1})\\
&= \mathbb{C}[xy^{-1}, y^{-1}] \cdot y^{-1} dx \oplus \mathbb{C}[xy^{-1}, y^{-1}] \cdot xy^{-1} dy \oplus \mathbb{C}[xy^{-1}, y^{-1}] \cdot y^{-2} dy.
\end{align*}

Furthermore, because of how we presented the modules $\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^1}^1(U_{\sigma_0})$ and $\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^1}^1 (U_{\sigma_1}) $ above, we have already calculated the transition functions! For example, on the intersection $U_{\sigma_0} \cap U_{\sigma_1} = \textrm{Spec}\left( \mathbb{C}[x,x^{-1},y,x^{-1}y] \right)$, we need to determine how to write $d(x^{-1})$ and $d(x^{-1} y)$ in terms of $dx$ and $dy$, respectively. The rules defining the module of differentials tell us that
$$
d(x^{-1}) = x^{-2} dx
$$
and
$$
d(x^{-1} y) = x^{-2} y dx + x^{-1} dy,
$$
and so we have our transition functions on $U_{\sigma_0} \cap U_{\sigma_1}$. The same process can be repeated on the other two intersections $U_{\sigma_0} \cap U_{\sigma_2}$ and $U_{\sigma_1} \cap U_{\sigma_2}$.

Comment: Thanks. So then, would it simply be $\Omega^{1}_{\mathbb{P^{1}}}(U_{\sigma_{2}}) = \mathbb{C}[xy^{-1},y^{-1}] \cdot d(xy^{-1}) \oplus \mathbb{C}[xy^{-1},y^{-1}] \cdot d(y^{-1}) = \mathbb{C}[xy^{-1},y^{-1}] \cdot y^{-1} dx \oplus \mathbb{C}[xy^{-1},y^{-1}] \cdot xy^{-2}dy \oplus \mathbb{C}[xy^{-1},y^{-1}] \cdot y^{-2} dy$?


On a related note. I understand that taking the spectrum gives the set of prime ideals, but I'm having a hard time picturing intuitively why this construction is used to define the affine open sets. Is there a good explanation for this?

Comment: Lastly, is there a good reason, why, when computing, it suffices to just take the free module on the formal symbols?

Thanks!

Comment: Your calculation of $\Omega_{\mathbb{P}^1}^1 (U_{\sigma_2}) $ looks to be correct. I'm not sure what your questions is about the prime spectrum - do you mean to ask why we define affine schemes to be the **prime** spectrum of a ring, instead of say the maximal spectrum?

Comment: I haven't formally read/learned about schemes yet. In terms of toric varieties, they simply define the affine open as $U_{\sigma} = Spec(\mathbb{C}[S_{\sigma}])$. Due to deadlines, I simply took that as granted so far. I understand the construction of the coordinate ring and semigroup. But what exactly does using Spec do? How would taking the prime ideals correspond to the affine opens? Would this just be a consequence of the Nullstellensatz?

Comment: For your second question, (admittedly I haven't read Cox, Little, & Schenck but...) most books define the module of differentials in exactly the way I did at the start of the answer i.e. as a quotient of this giant free module. Let me know if this is not the definition you were using!

Comment: Yes, that is the definition that was used. I guess I can see how the fact used for the computation follows now.

Comment: I'm still not entirely sure what your questions is, but if you're asking why we represent $\mathbb{P}^2 = U_{\sigma_0} \cup U_{\sigma_1} \cup U_{\sigma_2}$, then this will be (or should be an immediate consequence of) how you define projective space. Intuitively, you should think of the $U_{\sigma_i}$'s as planes so that, when you patch them together in the prescribed manner, you recover this "sphere".